# Select a child without it's sibblings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

How can i select only the `-` sign as a string using jquery or plain javascript?

I have no idea how i can do that.

```
<div class="container">
    -
    <div class="amount">
        $3
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery you can use `contents` and `-` will be the first node that you can get with `first` selector.

```js
const div = $(".container");
const node = div.contents().first();
console.log(node.text().trim())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  -
  <div class="amount">
    $3
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to replace the text node with some other text or html element you can use `replaceWith` jquery method.

```js
const div = $(".container");
const node = div.contents().first()

const newEl = $('<span>', {
  text: node.text().trim() + ' update',
  style: "color: red;"
})

node.replaceWith(newEl)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  -
  <div class="amount">
    $3
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Access the first `childNode` of the `.container`:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.container').childNodes[0]);
```

```html
<div class="container">
    -
    <div class="amount">
        $3
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to make sure that you get the content exactly, without selecting other children of the parent div, I suggest you should do it like this:

```js
    var content = $("#targetDiv")
                      .clone()    //copy your div
                      .children() //get all its children
                      .remove()   //destroy the children
                      .end()  //select the element again(now it doesn't have children)
                      .text() //get the text of your div;
        
    console.log(content);
```

```html
<div class="container" id="targetDiv">
  -
  <div class="amount">
    $3
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Check the snippet and see that it works.